# Accessing Kafka clusters using DNS

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are running Kafka Cluster(3 physical Node) in our production system, Our application pushes event to the Kafka which are consumed by Kafka Consumers owned by some diff team.

**Problem** : Now whenever we do change in our Data centre lets from DC1 to DC2, our Kafka IP's get changes and we have to ask our consumer to make the change in IP and do the deployment at their end, which looks weird to me.

**Question**: is there any way we can expose Kafka broker behind DNS and change the IP behind DNS while moving to DC2 from DC1 or vice versa to avoid change at consumer side? I am aware of advertised.listeners but will that work? and my concerns is security as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VIP and then use it in your consumer application config,
So consumer application exposed to VIP and actual IP can change,

like below

`kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: vip-host:9092`

Please see [Kafka FAQs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Producers) given for producer but should work the same way with consumers as well

Also this [issue](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-302+-+Enable+Kafka+clients+to+use+all+DNS+resolved+IP+addresses) raised and adopted might be helpful for more information.

Comment: VIP may have same IP but the connectivity that Kafka consumers are trying to make , how will that work ? will consumers needs restart? bcz instead of creating VIP, we tried creating 3 DNS for 3 broker node, but still Kafka Consumers needs retstart on DNS changes bcz Kafka meta data is not getting refreshed for consumers

Comment: @RE350 That's a problem with Java DNS caching, not Kafka

Comment: @cricket_007 Shouldn't this problem be related to metadata refresh interval??

Comment: @RE3 Which property are you referring to?